# How to run common commands just after running a for loop in a same batch file?

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to create a batch file, in which first I want to run for loop to clear event logs. Then run some different commands like sfc /scannow or systeminfo. But if I put these commands before for loop. It stops before running for loop. If I put these commands after writing for loop, it close cmd just after running for loop. Can someone provide the correct script to do all these tasks with a single batch file.

Example:

```
for /f %x in ('wevtutil el') do wevtutil cl "%x"
```

Comment: what kind of loop is it? can you provide an example? obviously alter any sensitive details.

Comment: for /f %x in ('wevtutil el') do wevtutil cl "%x"

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=1,2*" %%V IN ('bcdedit') DO SET adminTest=%%V
IF (%adminTest%)==(Access) goto noAdmin
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO (call :do_clear "%%G")
echo.
echo goto theEnd
:do_clear
echo clearing %1
wevtutil.exe cl %1
goto :eof
:noAdmin

Comment: what happens if you do a batch file with `systeminfo` command on one line, and `pause` on the following line? does it exit before the pause? If so then it isn't the loop that is causing the problem.

Comment: I don't know, what was the problem. But when I wrote the same script in a new notepad. It is working. But there is a problem. Actually, it is running 'systeminfo' and for loop. But cmd automatically close after for loop. Even after putting pause and cmd /k.

Comment: Why? Why putting code into a comment? Put it in the question as a code block ... 

Comment: As I am new, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

From your batch snippet, the only real 'unintended consequence' was the lack of an ampersand between the first two related IF statements.    Otherwise, the below runs on my Windows 7, and Windows 2008 servers (I emasculated the actual clearing of the event log):

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2*" %%V IN ('bcdedit.exe') DO SET adminTest=%%V & IF (%adminTest%)==(Access) goto :noAdmin 
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO (call :do_clear "%%G") 
    pause
    systeminfo.exe
    pause
    echo. 
    goto :exit
:do_clear 
    @echo =============
    echo clearing %1 
    wevtutil.exe gl %1 

    @echo =============

    goto :eof 

:noAdmin 

:exit
```

A batch program called without **call :**  will exit and not return to the first batch program.  I dont know how else your script might prematurely exiting.

Comment: I tried it. But it is not working. Some same lines are continuously running. My script was running completely, but I was trying to keep cmd open after running the script.

Comment: @MeetGill **pause** at the end to keep the windows

Comment: Open a cmd prompt and run the script from there.  I suggest never doing batch troubleshooting by clicking the batch file.

Comment: I just had to put pause and other command just after for loop. Now, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
cls
@ECHO OFF
pause
FOR /F "tokens=1,2*" %%V IN ('bcdedit') DO SET adminTest=%%V
IF (%adminTest%)==(Access) goto noAdmin
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO (call :do_clear "%%G")
sfc /scannow
Pause
echo.
echo goto theEnd
:do_clear
echo clearing %1
wevtutil.exe cl %1
goto :eof
:noAdmin
:EXIT
```